# How to change Json object request in a file every POST request using Java, Restassured, groovy

Tags: java, json, groovy

I am new to RESTful web services automated testing.

I have got JSON object that has email and password. I want to change this email every time my scripts does POST while running, because if am passing the same email it fails. Saying the email already exist.

**Code sample:**

```
public String postPeopleUsers() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException,
            ParseException {
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(path
                + "/resources/people/postpeopleusers.json"));
        JSONObject jsonPostBody = (JSONObject) obj;
        return postRequest(jsonPostBody, usersURI, 201, "data.id",
                "postpeopleUsers(String email)", false);
    }
```

**JSON request:**

```
{
    "email": "tesrteryrt00@Testewrtt00hrtyhrerlu.com",
    "password": "test123",
    "groups": [],
    "forename": "Test",
    "surname": "Er"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could use a dynamic test fixture or test harness to create unique email addresses on every run. Random values are probably fine for volatile tests that won't persist in memory between runs, but time is the best solution. Something like:

```
String email = "${System.currentTimeMillis()}@testdomain.com"
```

This uses the current system time in milliseconds (with granularity around 10 ms) to create a new email address that won't have been used previously.

-- Update --

Example test code which uses *very* simple fixture:

```
class JSONTest extends GroovyTestCase {
    String uniqueEmail
    final String JSON_FILENAME = "/resources/people/postpeopleusers.json"

    // I don't know the name of your class under test
    SystemUnderTest sut

    @Before
    void setUp() {
        uniqueEmail = "${System.currentTimeMillis()}@testdomain.com"
        sut = new SystemUnderTest()
    }

    @After
    void tearDown() {
        // You should actually clean up the datastore by removing any new values you added during the test here

        // Also remove the persisted JSON file
        new File(JSON_FILENAME).deleteOnExit()
    }

    @Test
    void testShouldProcessUniqueEmail() {
        // Arrange
        String json = """{
    "email": "${uniqueEmail}",
    "password": "test123",
    "groups": [],
    "forename": "Test",
    "surname": "Er"
}"""

        // Write the JSON into the file you read from
        File jsonFile = new File(JSON_FILENAME)
        // Only create the parent if it doesn't exist
        !jsonFile?.parent ?: new File(jsonFile?.parent as String).mkdirs()
        jsonFile.delete()
        jsonFile.createNewFile()
        jsonFile << json

        // I don't know what you expect the response to be
        final String EXPECTED_RESPONSE = "Something good here"

        // Act
        String response = sut.postPeopleUsers()

        // Assert
        assert response == EXPECTED_RESPONSE
    }

    // This is my mock implementation which prints the read JSON to a logger and I can verify the provided email
    class SystemUnderTest {
        public String postPeopleUsers() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException,
                ParseException {
            File jsonFile = new File(JSON_FILENAME)
            String contents = jsonFile.text
            def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(contents)

            logger.info(json)

            return "Something good here"
        }
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -ea
15:33:49,162  INFO JSONTest:45 - {forename=Test, email=1405463629115@testdomain.com, surname=Er, password=test123, groups=[]}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your time in answering my question. this is what am looking for but how can i cast the system.currentTimeMills to String i have used it like this.

Comment: Thanks for your time in answering my question. this is what am looking for but how can i cast the system.currentTimeMills to String? because it allows me to use it like this.  long email= System.currentTimeMillis();

Comment: i have got how to cast it to String. the problem am having now is to use the dynamic test fixture or test harness you mentioned above. i am using TestNg. thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you post your test code? I'll update my answer with a simple example.

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for your helps. I have been able  solved this problem with your idea and i have used a replaceFirst method to replace the email in Jsonfile with the currentMilli and i have got DELETE method on every test to delete what i posted. so it working fine. However i like your idea of clean up the datastore. i am going to try that to see how it works. Please will need your help in my coming tasks. as i am expected to test Validation, Filtering and Forms etc for our API and no ideas how to do this. i mean automated testing. thanks